# Chart.js, how to reduce space between labels and bars (horizontal bar chart)

Tags: chart.js

[image]

I am trying to find an option within chart.js that allows me to modify the space between bars and labels, but so far have been unsuccessful. I have tried the options under https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ticks.padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) to define the offset of the tick labels from the axis. In you case, it needs to be defined inside the `options.scales.yAxis` as follows:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        drawTicks: false
      },
      ticks: {
        padding: 5
      }
    }],
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but thanks for the advice. I tried both padding: 5 and padding: 0, but it didn't change the spacing.

After reading the documentation I believe this changes the spacing of the ticks, not of the labels, so it makes sense nothing was changed.

Comment: After messing with it some more I realized that these numbers were increased padding, so putting padding: 5 doesn't set the padding to 5, it increases the padding by 5.

As such using a negative number like padding: -20 accomplished my goal. Thanks for the help.